# Calling a general function within a recursive function in Python

Tags: python, function, recursion

I made a function do_n, which is supposed to call another function (as an object) 'n' times.

I have another function called print_n, which recursively prints a string 'n' times.

Calling 'print_n' using 'do_n', I expected 'hello' to be printed 20 times. However, it only prints 5 times as per the original function call.

Based on output, it seems the issue is that my 'do_n' function does not access do_n(func,i-1) to begin executing print_n again.

What is going wrong?

```
def print_n(s,n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    print(s)
    print_n(s,n-1)

def do_n(func,i):
    if i == 0: 
        return
    func()
    do_n(func,i-1)
        
do_n(print_n('hello',5),4)
```

Output:

```
(my_env) C:\Users\Rayyan\pyproj\first_script>python do_n.py
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Comment: You confused a reference to a function and calling (executing) it . `print_n` is a reference to the function you wrote. `print_n("asd", 2)` is actually calling it...

Comment: Seems to me this code should raise a NoneType not callable error at `func()` in the do_n body.

Answer (score 3):

**You're passing the output of `print_n` not `print_n` itself:**

Your question isn't perfectly clear, but this is the obvious issue.

`do_n(print_n('hello',5),4)` is passing the output of `print_n('hello',5)`, which is `None` to `do_n`. Assuming you want `do_n` to call `print_n`, with the arguments `('hello', 5)`, 4 times, try this code:

```
def print_n(s,n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    print(s)
    print_n(s,n-1)

def do_n(func,i, *a, **k):
    if i == 0: 
        return
    func(*a, **k)
    do_n(func,i-1, *a, **k)
        
do_n(print_n,4,'hello',5)
```

Output:

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

I'd like to note that it still works for other functions:

```
def other_func(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

def do_n(func,i, *a, **k):
    if i == 0: 
        return
    func(*a, **k)
    do_n(func,i-1, *a, **k)
        
do_n(other_func,4,1,2,3)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean, certainly. But do_n is supposed to work in a general sense for any function. This is based on a prompt / challenge from thinkpython2: https://imgur.com/a/Lq1Qpn1

Comment: @RayyanKhan it still works for any function. I added another example.

Comment: That's massively helpful. Thanks a lot - genuinely. I think I misinterpreted the original task in the textbook and made a mountain out of a molehill but it was a good learning experience nonetheless about calling a function by reference vs. object etc

Answer (score 0):

In the other answer you can see how to modify function `do_n` to allow it to take arguments for `func`.

Here is another alternative, using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), to call `do_n` with `print_n` without modifying the code of `do_n`:

```py
def print_n(s,n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    print(s)
    print_n(s,n-1)

def do_n(func,i):
    if i == 0: 
        return
    func()
    do_n(func,i-1)

from functools import partial

do_n(partial(print_n,'hello',5),4)
```

### Important note

Partial function application, just like recursion, is something that is done very often in functional languages like Ocaml or Haskell, but which is much rarer in python. In fact, I've never used `functools.partial` in any real project; I've only ever used it for fun or to answer theoretical stackoverflow questions. In a serious python program, the code for `do_n` and `print_n` would **not** use recursion, it would use a `for`-loop instead.